# mod_expires in apache htaccess

Tags: apache, http, .htaccess, caching

I am learning about apache and its various modules, currently i am confused about `mod_expires`. What i read so far is that using this module we can set future expiry header for static files so that browser need not to request them each time.

I am confused about the fact that if some one change css/js or any image file in between, how will browser come to know about it since we have already told the browser that this is not going to change say for next 1 year.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This Google article on [Optimize caching](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html) is a pretty good overview of this subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be possible for all provided content on your HTTP server, but you can simply change the name of the file to update a file on the client side from the server. At that point, the browser will download the new content.

Sometimes, for websites with less traffic it is far more functional to set the cache to a much lower value.

An expiration of 365 days should always be used with caution, and the fact that you can set an expiration of 1 year does not mean you always have to do it. In other words, do not fall prey to premature optimization.

A good example of setting cache expiration to 1 year are countries' flags, which are not likely to change. Also, be aware that with a simple browser refresh of a page, the client can discard the local cache and download the content again from the origin.

A good and easy way of testing all this is to use Firefox with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). With this extension, you can analyze requests and responses.

Here you can find the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) specifications.

Comment: Just to add. Browser also have a way of asking the server if the file has changed. It does this using the If-Modified-Since header. This way, if the file hasn't changed the browser doesn't download the file again, but uses the local cache. The (minor) downside compared to the Expires header is that the browser still has to connect to the server to do this check, and this takes a little bit of time.